# App has stopped while trying to open the second layout

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, crash, android-adapter

Im creating an app for scheduling, and when I choose a date and press select for moving to the other layout for creating a task for this date, the app stops.

This is my main:

```
public class CalendarActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

CalendarView calendarView;
TextView dateSelected;
Button selectButton;
Intent scheduleActivityIntent;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calendar);

    selectButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.selectButton);
    selectButton.setOnClickListener(new CalendarView.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v) {
            System.out.println("Button Clicked");

            //scheduleActivityIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ScheduleActivity.class);
            //startActivity(scheduleActivityIntent);
            startActivity(new Intent(CalendarActivity.this, ScheduleActivity.class));
        }
    });


    calendarView = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
    dateSelected = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dateSelected);
    calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(@androidx.annotation.NonNull CalendarView view, int year, int 
month, int dayOfMonth) {
            String date = dayOfMonth + "/" + (month+1) + "/" + year;
            dateSelected.setText(date);
        }
    });

 }
}
```

This is my second activity, which should be a list view of tasks:

```
public class ScheduleActivity extends CalendarActivity {

private static final String TAG = "ScheduleActivity";

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_schedule);

    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Started");
    ListView taskList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.schedule);

    //Create object insert
    Task haircut = new Task("Haircut", "21/01/2020", "14:00", 1, 2, "Go get a haircut");
    Task work = new Task("Work", "21/01/2020", "18:00", 6, 3, "Might be closing");

    //Should be made as a function in order to insert user's tasks

    //Creating Array adapter
    ArrayList<Task> taskListAdapter = new ArrayList<>();
    taskListAdapter.add(haircut);
    taskListAdapter.add(work);

    ScheduleAdapter adapter = new ScheduleAdapter(ScheduleActivity.this, R.layout.schedule_items, taskListAdapter);

    taskList.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}

This is the adapter:

```
public class ScheduleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter <Task>
{
private static final String TAG = "ScheduleAdapter";
private Context mContext;
int mResource;

//Default constructor for the adapter

public ScheduleAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull ArrayList<Task> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mResource = resource;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    //get the task info

    String name = getItem(position).getTaskName();
    String date = getItem(position).getTaskDate();
    String time = getItem(position).getTaskTime();
    int timeFinish = getItem(position).getTaskTimeFinish();
    int urgency = getItem(position).getTaskUrgency();
    String description = getItem(position).getTaskDescription();

    //create the task object with the info
    Task aTask = new Task(name, date, time, timeFinish, urgency, description);

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(mResource, parent, false);

    TextView tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.task_name);
    TextView tvTime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.task_time);
    TextView tvUrgency = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.task_urgency);

    tvName.setText(name);
    tvTime.setText(time);
    tvUrgency.setText(urgency);

    return convertView;
}
```

}

It seems from the Logcat like it crashes for:

```
2020-02-04 13:19:51.621 5841-5841/com.example.calendarview E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.calendarview, PID: 5841
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.from(LayoutInflater.java:232)
    at com.example.calendarview.ScheduleAdapter.getView(ScheduleAdapter.java:44)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2362)
    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1970)
    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:704)
    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:765)
    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1744)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2161)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1915)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:724)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2342)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2069)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1246)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6301)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:871)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:683)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:619)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:857)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

But I cannot find where

Comment: Can you post whole crash report?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

You're passing a null context in `LayoutInflater.from(mContext)`:

In your `ScheduleAdapter` constructor change

```
this.mContext = mContext;
```

to

```
this.mContext = context;
```